# Play app on Heroku using shared database and model updates

Tags: java, hibernate, heroku, playframework, sql-update

I'm toying with a Play 1.2.3 application (Java) using a Heroku instance with a shared database.

My question is: how to update the database schema once the application is deployed? In fact, how to even initialize the database, as it is empty initially and Hibernate ddl in PROD mode is disabled?

On the options I've tried:

1. Hibernate ddl auto is a big no-no in production
2. Play Evolutions are a mess if you use Hibernate, they are giving me too many problems during development to use them or rely on them
3. Heroku shared databases (the free option or the 20gb option) don't provide a Psql console access so you can't do it manually via scripts (as I would like)

This is an issue as the cost difference between the free db (15$/month) and the cheapest option that gives Psql access (200$/month) is huge, and for a bootstrapped "testing-the-waters" site it matters.

Any of you having this problem? How are you solving it?

Comment: Can't you just use the ddl updates in DEV and evolutions in PROD?

Comment: @Marius the "problem" is that if I create the evolutions script, Play also runs them in DEV. Also, I want to be able to test the changes in dev first, to avoid issues.

Comment: Ok, then I guess the Play-only solution would be to use Hibernate DDL until your code is ready for production. And then you'd create a new database with Fixtures (or restore a previous snapshot) to test your evolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative to the Heroku shared database is to use another database somewhere on AWS (your own EC2 server or a RDS database).

However if you want to stick with the shared database then you will need some way to execute a db script on Heorku.  There are a few different ways to do that.  The Play Evolutions are one option, but since you don't want to use those, you could use something like iBatis ScriptRunner.  Create a simple Java app that can run a sql script.  Here is a really simple example:

```
String dbUri = System.getenv("DATABASE_URL");
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + dbUri.getPath() + "?user=" + username + "&password=" + password;
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);

InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(sqlFile));

Reader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

ScriptRunner scriptRunner = new ScriptRunner(connection, false, true);
scriptRunner.runScript(reader);
```

Just put something like that class somewhere in your app dir and then run it with something like:

```
heroku run "java -cp lib/postgres.jar:tmp/classes foo.SchemaCreator"
```

Comment: Well, my main problem with Evolutions is not that I don't want to use them, is that I can't use the scripts in dev mdoe without them conflicting with Hibernate ddl updates. And disabling Hibernate ddl in dev mode gives you extra work. Your proposal seems interesting :)

Answer (score 3):

I use this one: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console.
It simply gives you an SQL console in your setup - I did not try to execute scripts.